# SwiftUI List content gets reset with selection

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-environment

Here is my issue: `MainView` displays `ChildView` and gives it an `EnvironmentObject` containing a set of selected items.

`ChildView` displays a list of selectable items(2 items in the example), and load the list when appearing.

The problem is that the `ChildView` content is reset to its original value (1 item in the example) when I tap on any row.

I tried to make my code as compact as possible.

```
struct MainView: View {
        
    @ObservedObject var model = MainViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ChildView().environmentObject(self.model)
        }
    }
}

class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var selection = Set<Stuff>()
    
    var formatted: String {
        return "\(self.selection.count)"
    }
}

struct ChildView : View {
    
    @ObservedObject var cm = ChildViewModel()
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MainViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            List(cm.demoData, id: \.self, selection: $model.selection) { stuff in
                Text("\(stuff.value)")
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, .constant(EditMode.active))
            .onAppear(perform: cm.load)
        }
    }
}

class ChildViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var demoData: [Stuff] = [Stuff(id: 1, value: "1")]
    
    func load() {
        self.demoData = [Stuff(id: 1, value: "1"), Stuff(id: 2, value: "2")]
    }

}

struct Stuff : Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var value: String
}
```

There is no problem if I don't use an environment object, but don't get how that causes the list to reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modify `MainViewModel` and it cause rebuild body, including `ChildView`.

If you have iOS 14 as target minimal supported system the simplest solution is to use `StateObject` as it preserves view data

```
struct ChildView : View {
    
    @StateObject var cm = ChildViewModel()     // << here !!

    // ... other code
```

Comment: For iOS13, what would be the possible solutions? Store my objects somewhere else?